# ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs

I am trying to check if `latitude` and `longitude` exist in my SQL database, as currently when they are undefined, it leaves my web app blank on load with the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined`

My code was originally

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    //If we know where the first device is, use that to center map ELSE just show the whole world map and let user navigate to them
    latitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude) ?  Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700 ,
    longitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) ? Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) : 100.8603,
    width:"80vw",
    height:"80vh",
    zoom:Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude) ? 10 : 1
  })
```

Where device.deviceData is pulling data from my table in SQL.

I adjusted it to make sure the length of the array from SQL was greater than 0, but this made no difference to the TypeError

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState ({
    latitude: device.deviceData.length > 0 ?  Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700 ,
    longitude: device.deviceData.length > 0 ? Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) : 100.8603,
...
```

and I've tried using console.log to make sure the length is really 0

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState => console.log(device.deviceData.length) ({
    latitude: device.deviceData.length > 0 ?  Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700 ,
    longitude: device.deviceData.length > 0 ? Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) : 100.8603,
...
```

Other tried fixes:

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState => console.log(device.deviceData.length) ({
    if (Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude)) {
      latitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude) ?  Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700 ,
      longitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) ? Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) : 100.8603,
...
```

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState => console.log(device.deviceData.length) ({
    if (Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude) != null) {
      latitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude) > 0 ?  Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700 ,
      longitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) > 0 ? Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) : 100.8603,
...
```

```
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState => console.log(device.deviceData.length) ({
    "latitude" in device.deviceData[0] {
      latitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude) > 0 ?  Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700 ,
      longitude: Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) > 0 ? Number(device.deviceData[0].longitude) : 100.8603,
...
```

But all of the above have had errors with the formatting, so I am not sure if they are viable options that I have simply gotten the syntax wrong to.

Any advice is greatly appreciated

EDIT: Posted the content of `device.deviceData` found under Redux Developer Tools

[image]

Comment: Whats the content of ``device.deviceData`` ?

Comment: It is a good idea to use chaining and checking each object(if it is defined/has some length etc.) before checking its property as mentioned in one answer. console.log(device.deviceData) and let us know what it is showing.

Comment: const [viewport, setViewport] = useState => console.log(device.deviceData.length). All your examples having this are using incorrect syntax. Aren't you getting a different error.

Comment: @AlumnoCabreado just added a screenshot of the content

Comment: @Henrik  Did you try to check length of deviceData in `zoom:Number(device.deviceData.lenght>0 ? device.deviceData.lenght[0].latitude : 0) ? 10 : 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined`. My guess is value of `device.deviceData` is `undefined`.

So,Please do verify with `console.log(device)` if deviceData field exists in device.

And, to fix above issue you can try

```
device.deviceData && device.deviceData.lenght>0 && device.deviceData[0].latitude 
? Number(device.deviceData[0].latitude): 38.2700
```

Much more cleaner syntax with optional chaining would be:

```
Number(device?.deviceData?.[0]?.latitude || 38.2700)
```

Comment: cconsole.log(device) shows other fields (which are also seen in the Redux developer tools I just screenshotted), but device.deviceData is an empty array/undefined

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! The page is still blank but the console is showing an unrelated error. Thank you!